# How full are KTX trains between Seoul and Busan usually?

Tags: trains, south-korea, seoul

I am visiting South Korea next month (last two weeks of April 2017) and, although I'm mostly staying in Seoul, I wanted to visit Busan for 2-3 days by taking a KTX train.  I'm considering buying a [Korail pass](http://www.letskorail.com/ebizbf/EbizBfKrPassAbout.do), which is cheaper than directly reserving/buying a roundtrip ticket.  However, as noted by the link,

> Seat reservations will be available after redeeming your Pass at the
>   ticket booths. Pass- holders, who fail to make reservations, may use
>   unreserved seats.

I'm planning to visit Busan during the weekdays, most likely a Tuesday -> Thursday trip.  I arrive in Seoul the Friday before this, and this would be the earliest time I could make seat reservations.

Do I have to worry at all about the trains being too full?  Would it be worth it to just forego the savings and reserve a roundtrip ticket to guarantee a seat?

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://seat61.com/SouthKorea.htm) already?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually, in my experience if you travel during the regular weekday and not on a weekend, during Seolal (Lunar New Year) or Chuseok (Harvest Moon Festival) there are several seats available between Seoul and Busan.

Comment: I will try not to forget to bounty this answer. This is why the site exists, first hand knowledge otherwise unattainable, this needs to be rewarded.

Comment: I'm grateful for the bounty bump ;o) Will add more info where applicable

Comment: FWIW: I ended up reserving a seat the night before each train ride, and I didn't have an issue.  Thanks @FullMetalFist for your help!